# How to show/hide Fileuploader control using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to hide/show some controls using jquery. But except fileuploader control all other controls are working  properly. How to hide a fileuploader control ?

My source code is,

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" class="style2">
        <asp:Label ID="lb12" runat="server" Text="CTC3"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtctc2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left" class="style2">
        <asp:Label ID="lb21" runat="server" Text="Certificate II"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my jquery is,

```
 $(window).load(function () {
     $('#<%= txtctc3.ClientID %>').hide();
     $('#<%= FileUpload3.ClientID %>').hide();
 });
```

Text box hides  when page loade but fileuploade control not hides. Please help me

How to hide below file control ?

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as, it will hide all the file upload controls.

```
 $('input[id$="files"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
 ClientIDMode="Static"
```

in file upload control as well.

Comment: then let this page run once, then from page source copy the rendered id of file control which should be something different from "FileUpload3" say ct2100FileUpload3. and modify your jquery code to  $('#ct2100FileUpload3').hide();

Answer (score 0):

change you code to:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('<%= "#" + txtctc3.ClientID %>').hide();
    $('<%=  "#" + FileUpload3.ClientID %>').hide();
});
```